# how to recheck username and emailid in edit profile page using stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In asp.net web page got username, password, emailid from login page using session. In edit profile page user want to change username and emailid and it has been updated in sql db. Before going to update first select the particular user record using session, get new username and new emailid check with records except that user record. If no one in that record means allow user to update otherwise show the msg "already exist". How to do this using stored procedure?

Any one pls provide stored procedure coding for this?

Comment: What have you tried? How does your code look like? What didn't work? Where are you stuck? And please, also read this: http://bit.ly/PerfectQuestion

Comment: I created asp.net login page from that page got username, password, emailid using session. After login in edit profile page user want to change his/her username and emailid.check that new username and password with other records except them.If not present means user allow to updated otherwise wont.how to do this using Stored Procedure?can pls provide coding?

Comment: thanks i got the logic...if i get stuck means i will msg u.

Comment: string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName); string Imagename = objUser.UserID + filename; FileUpload.SaveAs(@"D:\Shop_Web_21-6-12\ShopMonkey\Images" + Imagename); uploaded file is not stored in given physical path?above is my coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspUpdateUserName] 

    @newusername varchar(500),
    @newPassword varchar(500),
    @UserID int,
@Result int output

AS
BEGIN

    if exists(Select username from table 
    where username = @newusername and Password = @Password)
    Begin
        Print('already exist')
        Set @Result = -1
    End
    else
    Begin
         Update table
         Set username = @newusername,
         Password = @Password
         where UserID = @UserID
     Set @Result = UserID     

    End

END
```

Comment: string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName); string Imagename = objUser.UserID + filename; FileUpload.SaveAs(@"D:\Shop_Web_21-6-12\ShopMonkey\Images" + Imagename); uploaded file is not stored in given physical path?above is my coding..